# Can't get rails search form to work with simple_form and sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, simple-form, sunspot, railscasts

I have a simple rails app that uses the simple_form gem for forms and I am trying to set up a search form using sunspot. I have followed the instructions in Ryan Bates' railscast on setting up sunspot and it works fine except for the fact that I know I am not using the simple_form helpers and I would like to. Here is the code for the search form:

From _search.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag rules_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

From rules_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @search = Rule.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @rules = @search.results

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @rules }
  end
end
```

Like I mentioned this works for now but the question is:

**How can I alter the _search.html.erb for to use the simple_form format?**

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it working by giving the form a `symbol` the same name as the input and specifying the URL. Take a look at the URL your `form_tag` produces and what `simple_form_for` produces with just a path. So try this in your form partial:

```
<%= simple_form_for :search,  url: rules_path , :method => :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :query, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

if that doesn't work, study what your `form_tag` produces and try to replicate that with simple_form.

Answer (score 2):

For to do this I'm using simple_form the next way:

**1. Define a form(I use haml)**

```
=simple_form_for :search, url: search_path(:search), :method => :get  do |f|
 =f.input :q
 =f.submit "Search"
```

**2. Define a route in routes.rb**

```
get '/jobs/search/:q', :to => 'jobs#search', :as => :search
```

**3. Define a method inside your controller (in my case jobs_controller.rb)**

```
  def search
   @search = params[:search][:q]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for rules_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :search %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried that and got the following error: `undefined method `rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_rule_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103bdc0c8>:0x00000103b733e8>`

Comment: Woud you try `<%= simple_form_for rules_path do |f| %>` instead please?

Comment: When I try that the submit button says "Save /rules" and attempts to save a new rule when clicked.

Comment: What is missing is the `:method => :get`, sorry!

Comment: That still has the problem where the submit action links to saving an empty new action link the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use my guide to get simple_form in-place search boxes working with AJAX: http://rexstjohn.com/in-place-ajax-search-box-with-ruby-simple_form-gem/